# Android NDK java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am trying to call a method from testRTSPClient.cpp in java. but i am getting following error. 
03-06 18:36:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(6938): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: play

my java class is RTSPClientActivity.java
and .cpp file is testRTSPClient.cpp

following is method i have made in .cpp file

void Java_my_pakg_RTSPClientActivity_play(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
... 
}

```
public class RTSPClientActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        try

        {
            System.loadLibrary("testRtspClient");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static native void playstream();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rtsp_layout);
        play();
    }
}
```

i have seen relative questions on internet bus no answer was usefull, i am unable to find where i am mistaken.. 
Thanks...

Comment: java file code is
public class RTSPClientActivity extends Activity {
 static
    {
        try
        {  
        
            System.loadLibrary("testRtspClient");

        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 static native void playstream();
   
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.rtsp_layout);
  play();
 }
}

Comment: well sorry for bad formatting, new here at stackoverflow...

Comment: you should put the code into the question. There's no formatting in the comments.

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE .  Also, look at the logcat lines *before* the exception; sometimes you will find a message from `dlopen()` there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
static native void playstream();
```

to

```
static native void play();
```

as same entry you defined in cpp

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your C++ function definitions in `extern "C"`.  Here's an example:

[How do I prepare my .cpp files for the Android ndk to build them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656055/how-do-i-prepare-my-cpp-files-for-the-android-ndk-to-build-them/7665923#7665923)

Answer (score 0):

Check please function signatures, they should be the same in C and Java code.
The best way is to create .h file from class with native functions.

within your command line go to your project/bin/classes and perform there

```
javah -jni com.mypackage.myclass
```